# rosjava wifi scanning

Tags: ros, wifi, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello..

i have a question..

how can i make the project that wifi-scanning in rosjava ?

i search the API in http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/javadoc/index.html

but i cannot find valid method..

can i use android lib in rosjava?

or.. is there other way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35017/rosjava-wifi-scanning/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your application is running on Android, you should use the Android API to interact with wifi.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0